# Sync iPhone Over RDP via USB

Tags: remote-desktop, itunes, iphone

Is it possible to synch an iPhone to an iTunes library over USB via a remote desktop connection?  The library is located on the remote computer, and the iPhone is connected to the local computer.

I have tried sharing the USB port, but iTunes doesn't seem to notice it.

[image]

Comment: ITunes requires to be able to see the device itself in order to sync your library.  Since a USB device is not shared over a RDP session one of the only requirements iTunes has is not fulfilled.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, you can share devices over RDP, including USB devices.